# Alter column script not working

Tags: sql-server, database, alter-table

I ran the following script to change the the field 'Asdes' from nvarchar(255) to varchar(150) in the table 'Verdata'.

```
Alter table Verdata
Alter column asdes varchar(150)
```

The script runs without errors yet the field remains unmodified when I enter the table design mode.

Comment: close the design view, and reopen it, or better reconnect to the server and see.

Comment: just curious... why would you need to reduce the size of a variable character column?

Comment: Does sp_help show the correct size?

Comment: I wanted the field 'asdes' to be a foreign key, this table was imported from MS access and the size(as I am sure you know) defaults on import to the string field type nvarchar(255). SQL server did not want to create the foreign key unless it was the same size as the source field. I ended up altering the table using the design view, I was just curious as to why the above query had no effect.

Comment: @kritner efficiency, nvrachar takes twice as much space, rule of thumb is to use smallest field size required to save on disk space and I believe also translates to query performance gains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding semicolon at the end of the query or put 'GO' after it